# Need advise on new SharePoint Project

Tags: 2013

Disclaimer, I am fairly new to SharePoint, I have a broad background in Access Databases and Access web applications.

I've been tasked with the following. I've put together a project site for our IT project manager. This site is currently made of 2 list, Business Requirements, and IT Project.

The project manager wants to be able to enter new items within the Business Requirements list. Upon doing so, if the business requirements item corresponds with a project, she will use a lookup field to "link" the project and business requirements together. The problem I am running into... After assigning a project number, to a business requirement, she wants the business requirement ID number to populate within a field on the project list. Potentially creating a 1 to many relationship between the two list. I don't know the best way to go about doing this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint, there is a lookup field which can be used to build a relationship between lists. You can follow below steps to create a lookup

1. Go to your project list.
2. From the ribbon go to list settings.
3. Create a new column.
4. From the field type you need to select the "Lookup"
5. You have to select the lookup list as your "Business Requirements" list
6. Check the columns you need to see in project list.
7. Check "Allow multiple items" and save
8. While you create a project it will show the BR documents as a multi-select option.

Go through [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORFXaG4M5lI) for a complete explanation.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't achieve what I'm needing to do. 

They want to use a lookup column from within Business requirements, that references the project ID, from the project list. Once that field is populated, they then want the Business Requirements ID to show up on in the corresponding project list. I tried using a workflow to do this, but it errors out every time.

Comment: This is what I understand, you need a project id reference in the Business Requirement Document list. And show the business id in the Project list. Is this right?

Comment: Hey Venkat, 

They have added a 3rd list on me now. I have 3 list, Business Requirements / Project / Developments. 

They want to add an item to the Business Requirements list, use a lookup that references the developments list and link those two list together. 

They then want to use a lookup field in Developments, and associate those with the Project. 

So Business Requirements links to Developments (this can be a many to many relationship). Then Developments links to Projects (this will be a 1 to many relationship, with the limited possibility of being a many to many)

Comment: Essentially they want to be able to look at the project, within the project list and see all the associated business requirements and developments. As well as if they look at an item in the business requirements list, they can see what project it is associated with. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: For that, you have to create a lookup in both lists and update the both lists. Like in Project list create a lookup for Business Requirement and in Business Requirements list create a lookup for Projects. Then update their mapping manually as there is no direct way for this

Comment: You can create a lookup list for more than one also but need to update manually.